# I have a number and I would like to get the closest number less than and closest number greater than inside a jquery array

Tags: javascript, jquery

So i have array of numbers [0, 245, 678, 978, 1647] and would like to get the closest number less than and the closest number greater than my variable. So if my variable is say 412 i would like 245 returned and 678 returned separately.

Thanks.

Comment: Please post you code so far, what have you tried?

Comment: And it's not a jQuery array. This is simple Javascript array...

Comment: I have tried this to get the smaller value however it seems to be inconsistent
    var sm = [];
    for( i = 0, l = arr.length; i < l; i++ ) {if (cur_pos_x > arr[i]) {
       sm.push(arr[i]);
      }
     }
     sm.sort();
     console.log('sm: '+sm[sm.length - 1]);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do that

```
function closest(arr, numb) {
    var o = {
        max : Math.max.apply(null, arr), 
        min : Math.min.apply(null, arr)
    };

    arr.forEach(function(itm) {
        if (itm > numb && itm < o.max) o.max = itm;
        if (itm < numb && itm > o.min) o.min = itm;
    });

    return o;
}
```

to be used as

```
closest([0, 245, 678, 978, 1647], 412); // returns {max : 678, min : 245}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/nP4Xp/)

It starts with the lowest and highest numbers in the array, then it iterates to see if there is a number that is higher than the passed in number, and at the same time lower than the max number, and as it updates the max number while iterating you end up with whatever is closest to the passed in value etc.

Comment: Worked a treat. Thank you.